# How do I use Postgres on Linux when the databases themselves reside on a Windows server?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, samba, postgresql

I am using Oracle VirtualBox on a Windows host.  The Windows host has a regular Windows file share.  I want to use this folder for storage (of Postgres databases).

I know how to create Windows file shares. I know how to mount file systems in Linux. How do I mount a regular file system in Linux that is supported by a Windows file share?

I can use the smb prompt interactively between the Linux guest and the Windows host.  But I do not know how to have regular Linux operations on files on a Windows share.  I only know how to use the smb client.  These interactive commands require special smb commands initially.

I have installed Postgres on the Linux guest.  I want to have the Postgres database files be stored on on a Windows share.  I do not have storage capacity on my Linux server.

vboxsf does not support the folder permissions necessary to set up Postgres.  That is the Postgres data directory cannot be on vboxsf file shares in my experience.    My Linux guest is Centos 7.3 with no GUI.   What do I do to use Samba without an interactive prompt or otherwise house the Postgres database on a Windows file share?  There may be a solution that is outside of Samba and Oracle VirtualBox technology (e.g., vboxsf).

I have successfully configured network operations between the Windows host and Linux guest.

To clarify, my goal is to have Postgres databases of several gigabytes reside on a Windows server that work through a Linux server.  The Linux server will have Postgres installed on it.  The Postgres databases do not need to work with the Windows server.  The Postgres databases cannot be on the Linux server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This combination of technology is not a great idea. See https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/54F7F625.6020907%40hogranch.com - particularly because the db is not small.

If you are going to do it, mount the windows share to /var/lib/pgsql/x.x/data  (where x.x is the version of Postgres

You have a few options for setting up the mount - ensure smb-utils is installed and modify /etc/fstab

You might want to look at an alternative like NFS instead - or even better (i dont use Virtualbox so dont know how practical it is) create a block device or use a file as an additional block device for the Linux VM and put the data on that.